# How to forbid the use of arrow keys on the keyboard with pushbuttons in Qt

Tags: qt

I am doing a simple project in Qt to rotate a cube, and I have problem with arrows on keyboard and pushbuttons.

I have two pushbuttons, when I click the first pushbutton the cube rotates to right, the second pushbuttons is used to rotate it to left.

I also have two arrows keys on the keyboard, up and down, and theirs function is the same as the pushbuttons. When I press the up arrow the cube rotate right and so on.

The problem is when I start the application, the arrows instead of controlling the rotate, select the buttons. So I need to know where I can change this options, i.e, turn off navigation action of the arrow keys in pushbuttons.

Projet is made by inheriting QMainWindow.

Comment: Try this: `pushButton->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)`

Answer (score 4):

Be default, `QPushButton` (like many other subclasses of `QWidget`) will have a default way of handling keyboard focus. In the case of buttons, arrow keys move the keyboard focus from one button to the next to facilitate navigating through the window and interacting with the widgets without a mouse.

As hank suggested in a comment, you can force the `QPushButton` to not accept keyboard focus by calling its `setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)`, but that will only work in the particular case where the push buttons were the only ones in your `QMainWindow` that could steal focus. If your have other widgets in there (e.g. a `QLineEdit`), when the focus ends up there, the arrow keys will still not function right because the `QLineEdit` will grab those keys, and do nothing.

The more flexible way to solve your problem is to either install an event filter on each of your `QMainWindow`'s child widgets, and have that event filter forward the arrow key events to the functions that rotate your cube (while letting everything else pass through to allow any other event to be processed by the appropriate widget).

Another solution would be to have your cube widget grab all keyboard events with `QWidget::grabKeyboard()`. That would ensure that every keyboard event gets sent to that widget, no matter where the keyboard focus is. When you want to let other widgets receive keyboard events, you will need to call `QWidget::releaseKeyboard()` to ungrab it.